# Cannot remove "," in data.frame(they said "Unexpected numeric constant.")

Tags: r

I have that df.

[image]

I'd like to remove comma in field in cloumn "2019" ~ "2015".

So I used the following function.

```
(df <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$2019)))
```

but The R said

> "Error : that is unexpected numeric constant.
> df <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$2019)
> ^       "

How can I solve the problem??

Comment: Column names aren't supposed to start with a number. Since you have an invalid name, you'll need to quote it with backticks: `df <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$\`2019\`))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to loop over all the columns and remove commas and turn them to numeric.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(',', '', x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
           mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_remove_all(., ",")))
```